# MySQL Query - Sum one related table - Count another related table

Tags: mysql

The Count works fine with one related table, but when I add the Sum I get overinflated results in the Count.

```
SELECT Orders.kp_OrderID AS `Order #`, 
    Orders.t_ServiceLevel AS `Service Level`, 
    Customers.t_CustCompany AS Company, 
    Orders.t_JobName AS `Job Name`, 
    Orders.t_JobStatus AS `Status`, 
    Orders.d_JobDue AS Due, 
    Orders.ti_JobDue AS Time, 
    COUNT(OrderItems.kf_OrderID) AS `Line Item`, 
    SUM(
        `OrderItemComponents`.`n_QuantityPrintMaterial` * (
        `OrderItemComponents`.`n_WidthInInches` * `OrderItemComponents`.`n_HeightInInches` / 144
            )
        ) AS SqFt, 
    Orders.nb_JobFinished AS Finished
FROM Orders 
     INNER JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.kp_OrderID = OrderItems.kf_OrderID
     INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.kf_CustomerID = Customers.kp_CustomerID
     INNER JOIN OrderItemComponents ON OrderItemComponents.kf_OrderID = Orders.kp_OrderID
    WHERE Orders.d_JobDue > (
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
         )
    GROUP BY Orders.kp_OrderID
    ORDER BY `Line Item` DESC
```

Comment: I'm trying to return Orders w/ a count of related rows from OrderItems while at the same time summarizing related rows from OrderItemsComponents.  I get the correct results until I add the Sum and the last Inner Join for OrderItemComponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your COUNT line to:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT OrderItems.kf_OrderID) AS `Line Item`
```

When adding the line

```
INNER JOIN OrderItemComponents 
  ON OrderItemComponents.kf_OrderID = Orders.kp_OrderID
```

you returned many more rows since an OrderItem can, I assume, contain multiple components.

**UPDATE**

Try using this in place if your COUNT statement:

```
(SELECT COUNT(OrderItems.kf_OrderID) 
 FROM OrderItems.kf_OrderID 
 WHERE OrderItems.kf_OrderID=Order.kf_OrderID) AS `Line Item`,
```

Comment: I'm trying to return the order w/ the count of related rows for OrderItems.  W/ this solution I'm getting "1" as the answer for the # of related rows in OrderItems for each Order.

Comment: @user1551971, I amended my answer to use a separate subselect.

Comment: Holger - I think its close, but know I'm returning the total count of all rows related to the subset.  Obviously I'm no expert. 1285 rows returned and 45697 OrderItems returned for each row.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you get each order item repeated for every order item component. One solution might be `COUNT(DISTINCT OrderItems.kf_OrderID)` so you don't count the same item twice.