# MySQL - Count records in one table and sum records in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is similar to this question: [MySQL Query - Sum one related table - Count another related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652394/mysql-query-sum-one-related-table-count-another-related-table) but I cannot make it work for me.

I have 3 tables:

- `Event`
- `Attendee`
- `Gifts`

For each `Event` we need to summarize the number of `Attendees`, and the total amount of `Gifts`.  An `Attendee` may, or may not, receive a gift.

I can get it working so that if I ignore the gift totals, I get the right answer with this query:

```
SELECT event.name AS name, count( * ) AS num_attendee
FROM attendee
RIGHT JOIN event on event.id = attendee.event_id 
WHERE event.company_id =6
GROUP BY event.id
```

But I have no idea how to sum the gifts (i.e. `Gift.Amount` values) given to all `Attendees` for each event.  When I try to simply join in the `Gift` table based upon `event_id` all the numbers go wacky.

Comment: Do you have some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: You are probably getting [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) because atendees and gifts both have more than one record per event_id. If this is the case use [derived table](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-derived-tables-to-calculate-aggregate-values) to perform aggregation on child table(s) before you do a join to parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is O'K in MS-SQL 2000:

```
SELECT event.name AS name, count( * ) num_attendee ,amount
FROM attendee
RIGHT JOIN event on event.id = attendee.event_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT event_id,amount=SUM(Amount)
    FROM Gifts
    GROUP BY event_id
) Gifts ON Gifts.event_id=event.id
WHERE event.company_id =6
GROUP BY event.name,amount
```

Comment: Worked great - thanks much!  Man, I struggled with this for awhile!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the join correctly?  You should have both the event and attendee in the gifts table:

```
from attendee right join
     event
     on event.id = attendee.event_id right join
     gifts
     on event.id = gifts.event_id and attendee.id = gifts.attendee_id
```